# What can go wrong with scripts that have no protocol in their src URL?

Tags: javascript, security, cross-domain, xss

Is it totally safe to omit protocol from src URL of scripts that are served from both `http` and `https` protocols?

For example jQuery code over Google CDN can be accessed like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Facebook and jQuery are suggesting developers to have the script tag with a source that doesn't have protocol in it. Their CDN serve both HTTP and HTTPS protocols so if page that have script in it was served in HTTP or HTTPS, it will fetch script with matched protocol. This is the good side of this practice.

Can anything go wrong with this? I'm mostly concerned about security.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it totally safe to omit protocol from src URL of scripts that are
> served from both http and https protocols?

Yes.

When using a `network-path reference` the browser will automatically requests the file with the `https:` protocol when the browser is viewing the page through HTTPS otherwise it will request the file with `http:`.

However, when using the `network-path reference` viewing the file locally, the browser will request the file using the `file:` protocol.

There is more information here: [**RFC 3986**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2). It does not mention security but the nature of the behavior ensure https/http is chosen as required.

To quote:

> **4.2.  Relative Reference**
>
> A relative reference takes advantage of the hierarchical syntax
> (Section 1.2.3) to express a URI reference relative to the name space
> of another hierarchical URI.
>
> ```
>   relative-ref  = relative-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
>
>   relative-part = "//" authority path-abempty
>                 / path-absolute
>                 / path-noscheme
>                 / path-empty
> ```
>
> The URI referred to by a relative reference, also known as the
> target    URI, is obtained by applying the reference resolution
> algorithm of    Section 5.
>
> A relative reference that begins with two slash characters is
> termed    a network-path reference; such references are rarely used.
> A    relative reference that begins with a single slash character is
> termed an absolute-path reference.  A relative reference that does
> not begin with a slash character is termed a relative-path reference.
>
> A path segment that contains a colon character (e.g., "this:that")
> cannot be used as the first segment of a relative-path reference, as
> it would be mistaken for a scheme name.  Such a segment must be
> preceded by a dot-segment (e.g., "./this:that") to make a relative-
> path reference.